# Formatting a date column with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, date

I have the following problem. I have a dataframe with a date column. The date is saved as str and mostly in the following formats: `df[dates]=[['5 July 2023'], ['Brussels, 18 September 1998'],['Frankfurt/Brussels, 18 September 1998'], ['Frankfurt,Brussels, 18 September 1998'], ['11 April 2019[updated on 11 April 2019 at 11:15 CET ]']]`

I want to have every date in the column the following format: `df[dates]=[['5 July 2023'], ['18 September 1998']...]`

Is there a way to use regular expressions to bring the above mentioned cases in the right format? How should I treat the cases where no date is provided (they are only few)? Should I delete the entire row in such a case or should I replace the text with a random fill date that I specifically use for such cases?

I tried a few regular expressions myself but I could not get the dates formatted the way I needed them to be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I forgot some information. Sometimes date are also formatted like this: 11 April 2019[updated on 11 April 2019 at 11:15 CET ]

Comment: That is not enough information to understand your problem. Please provide your code snippet.

Comment: This is the format of the column of my dataframe: `df[dates]=[['5 July 2023'], ['Brussels, 18 September 1998'],['Frankfurt/Brussels, 18 September 1998'], ['Frankfurt,Brussels, 18 September 1998'], ['11 April 2019[updated on 11 April 2019 at 11:15 CET ]']]` I want to have every date in the column the following format: `df[dates]=[['5 July 2023'], ['18 September 1998']...]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming you want the date as a string rather than as datetime/Timestamp. The example below shows one approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

s1= "Brussels, 18 September 1998"
s2 = "11 April 2019[updated on 11 April 2019 at 11:15 CET ]"
s3 = "no date in this one 1234"

df = pd.DataFrame({'txt': [s1,s2, s3]})

df['date'] = df['txt'].str.extract(r'(\d+\D\D+\d+)',)

print(df)
```

gives:

```
                                                 txt               date
0                        Brussels, 18 September 1998  18 September 1998
1  11 April 2019[updated on 11 April 2019 at 11:1...      11 April 2019
2                           no date in this one 1234                NaN
```

Comment: Hi this solution worked for me. Thank you! After converting the date to a uniform format I further transformed it with `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)` to an actual date and it worked fine!

Comment: If you have sny problems converting some date strings then I recommend this parser [link](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use `r'\b(\d{1,2} w+ \d{4})\b'` to create a new column.
It picks out the first "day month year" encountered.
Do this by
[apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)ing
your custom function,
which can return `None` or `"1 January 1970"`
for the handful of cases where the regex found no date.

Invoke [.to_timestamp()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html)
on the column,
so you can easily verify and format those dates.

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
the code you finally settle on.